# oracle php lock record

Tags: php, oracle

I have this problem.. i am trying to use the lock record for the update. I am using php, and i use oracle as the database. i didnt understand fully but i have managed to copy the previous developer code and make it working.

It is using the odbc_exec(), odbc_fetch_row(). I think that this is suppose to be use for microsoft access data base. But i don't know. And i am also using jquery to fetch this php file(using jquery post) and append to the current page.

But now my senior request me to make sure that if a person is editing one record. then the other cant edit it anymore. They said that something about not closing the connection. can php not close connection to database after 1 page is loaded (when it is using jquery to get the page like mine does)? from what i know, if a page is loaded. the connection to the database is closed.

I want to try this code but i am afraid if i am wrong and the connection would hang.

Now my sql is like this for select all company.

```
$sqlStr ="select * from company";
$rs  = odbc_exec($GblConnOra , $sqlStr);
while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)){
   $company_name=odbc_result($rs,"company_name");
    $company_id=odbc_result($rs,"company_id");
}
```

And for select the company to edit

```
$sqlStr ="select * from company where company_id='34'";
$rs  = odbc_exec($GblConnOra , $sqlStr);
while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)){
   $company_name=odbc_result($rs,"company_name");
}
```

The updating

```
$sqlStr ="update compay set company_name=? where company_id=?";
$stmt = odbc_prepare($GblConnOra , $sqlStr);
$res = odbc_execute($stmt, array($company_name, $company_id));
```

i think the sql will be like this. to lock the record.

```
$sqlStr ="select * from company for update skip locked";
$rs  = odbc_exec($GblConnOra , $sqlStr);
while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)){
   $company_name=odbc_result($rs,"company_name");
    $company_id=odbc_result($rs,"company_id");
}
```

can i do this?
what would my sql be for selecting a row to edit?
what would my sql be for updating the row?

And from my understanding, this lock would be release after an update commit or rollback is call.

Comment: [This](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) would be a good start...

Comment: Thank you  very much for the link. but it tells me about the use of OCI8 in php. I now understand the use of odbc thing and Oci thing. But still i needed to know if my sql is right and the sql to update the table, lock the row. could u help me with this also?

Comment: @NuiAini Per my understanding, you can't lock the row, because PHP, when used as a server-side language (which I think you are doing such), works in a request-response way, that means your PHP script only have a life time of a request, so when the page is loaded in your client's browser, the connection is closed. Plus there will be no way to distinct client A and client B who both open the same page.

Comment: @Passerby that is what i thought too.. thank you for your reply.